# Swift: implementing a new item dialogue like 'add alarm' in clock app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

[image]

I want to implement an add new item dialogue in my app similar to add alarm dialogue in the clock app (screenshot). Prior to this moment I always used the same storyboard scene design for iphone and ipad with autolayout to make it look good on both devices. But I'm wondering how can I implement a view similar to Add Alarm dialogue - it looks very compact on both iphone and ipad especially because on ipad it's a separate small view that is not stretched across the screen. Can somebody please point me how to implement it? I don't really need the code, just some directions that can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Found it in the apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html